# Unfair or dirty in Japanese

Tags: word-requests

I believe I heard it a number of times in anime. And I heard it just now:

tsurui na (you fight dirty)

But I decided to look in a dictionary, and can't find the word. Which is strange because the word must be common. Or maybe the pronunciation differs slightly. How do you write the word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely you heard the word **ずるい** (zurui). Depending on your native language, distinguishing between tsu and zu might be more difficult.

Comment: It might help to add that at that position ず is often pronounced like “dzu” and it could make it even harder to distinguish it from つ for speakers of some languages.